# Issues with route change on resume with angularjs and cordova push notifications plugin

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, push-notification

Trying to reroute when an app is resumed; really not sure why this isn't working. The resuming alert appears, and a topic id appears as well. Thoughts?

More details: on receiving the notification, lastMessage is stored. When the app is resumed, relevant data is retrieved, but $location.path() isn't working. The same call to $location.path does work elsewhere.

On resume function inside of the notification factory:

```
function onResumeListener() {
document.addEventListener('resume', function() {
    alert("resuming");
  var lastMessage;

  try {
    lastMessage = JSON.parse($window.localStorage.getItem('lastMessage'));
      alert(lastMessage.topic_id);
      //$location.path("/chat/" + lastMessage.topic_id);
      //tried putting route change here as well

  } catch (exception) {
      alert("failure");
    lastMessage = '';
  }

    $location.path("/chat/" + lastMessage.topic_id);

});
}
```

on receiving apple notifications

```
function onNotificationAPN(e) {
$window.localStorage.setItem('lastMessage', JSON.stringify(e));
$rootScope.$broadcast('push.message', e);

if (e.alert) {}
if (e.sound) {}
if (e.badge) {}
}
```

on receiving android notifications

```
function onNotificationGCM(e) {
$window.localStorage.setItem('lastMessage', JSON.stringify(e));

switch (e.event) {
  case 'registered':
    localStorage.setItem('deviceId', e.regid);
    $rootScope.$broadcast('push.register', e.regid);
    break;
  case 'message':
    //alert('broadcast');
    $rootScope.$broadcast('push.message', e);
    break;
  case 'error':
    $log.error('Error event received: ' + e);
    break;
  default:
    $log.error('Unknown event received: ' + e);
    break;
}
}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? I'm experiencing the same problem

Comment: My team and I did finally find a solution, but I don't remember exactly what it was. Don't think we used timeouts though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it (a little hacky) by wrapping the location change in a timeout:

```
$timeout(function(){$location.path('/yourPath')},0);
```

I don't know why it solves the problem (at least for me), but I suppose it might be that the full angular functionality isn't available when you click the notification and postpoing the location change on the next free moment (timeout of 0) helps. It might also be that the (additional) apply, that `$timeout` sends does the trick...